# R change axis scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and want to change the y-axis-scaling for the following plot:

[image]

Instead of having each exact value possible in the dataset, I want to have y-axis-scaling from 0 to 12 in steps of 1. So I want every country's value to be mapped to one of the Values from 0 to 12.

currently what i have is:

`p <- ggplot(data=merged_set, aes(x=cntry, y=num)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

`p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))`

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: You may try with `scale_y_continuous` with `breaks` and `labels`

Comment: Please check your data. The `num` variable is most likely of type character.

Comment: @markus thanks, that was it. Now I have a scaling of 0 - 3 - 6 - 9, what would I have to change in order to get a single step scaling like 0,1,2,3...

Comment: That would be something like `scale_y_ continuous(breaks = function(x){seq(x[1], x[2], by = 1})` (untested). Or just `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:12)`.